# UISearchResultsController crashing on device (index beyond bounds for empty array)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisearchbar, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I'm using `UISearchResultsController` to filter data from a `fetchedResultsController`.  Here is the relevant code:

In `RootVieweController.h`:

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController <NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, AdditionViewControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate> {

    NSArray *filteredListContent;   
    NSString *savedSearchTerm;
    NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
    BOOL searchIsActive;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *filteredListContent;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *savedSearchTerm;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger savedScopeButtonIndex;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL searchIsActive;
```

In `RootViewController.m`:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [snip]
    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 40)];
    searchBar.delegate = self;
    searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Scope 1", @"Scope 2", nil];
    [searchBar sizeToFit];
    searchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
    [searchBar release];
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 40)];

    UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:searchBar contentsController:self];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setSearchDisplayController:) withObject:searchDisplayController];

    [searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDataSource:self];
    [searchDisplayController setSearchResultsDelegate:self];
    [searchDisplayController release];

    self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] count]];

    if (self.savedSearchTerm) {
        [self.searchDisplayController setActive:self.searchIsActive];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setSelectedScopeButtonIndex:self.savedScopeButtonIndex];
        [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar setText:savedSearchTerm];
    
        self.savedSearchTerm = nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (theTableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        NSLog(@"Search Cells: %i", [self.filteredListContent count]);
        return [self.filteredListContent count];
    }
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    NSLog(@"Normal cells: %i", [sectionInfo numberOfObjects]);
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

-(void)configureCell:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Called from cellForRowAtIndexPath

    Object *object = nil;
    if (self.searchIsActive) {
        object = [[self filteredListContent] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    } else {
        object = [fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    [snip]
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Search functions

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString *)searchText scope:(NSString *)scope {
    if ([scope isEqualToString:@"Scope 1"]) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scope1 BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
        self.filteredListContent = [[[self fetchedResultsController] fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    } else {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"scope2 BEGINSWITH[cd] %@", searchText];
        self.filteredListContent = [[[self fetchedResultsController]fetchedObjects] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    }
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller willShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)theTableView {
    NSLog(@"Showing search results");
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:
      [self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];

    NSLog(@"Reloading for string");

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    [self filterContentForSearchText:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar text] scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    NSLog(@"Reloading for scope");

    return YES;
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.rowHeight = 55;
    self.searchIsActive = YES;
}

-(void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    self.searchIsActive = NO;
}
```

This works great in the simulator. But on a device, it crashes on `object = [[self filteredListContent] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` from `configureCell` when trying to show the searchResultsTableView. I get the error `[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 7 beyond bounds for empty array`. Always index 7. What am I missing here?

### --UPDATE--

Fixed: flipped the `searchIsActive` `BOOL` to switch on `searchDisplayControllerDidBeginSearch` instead of `searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch` and `searchDisplayControllerWillEndSearch` instead of `searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch`. That keeps the table from trying to configure cells that don't exist. No clue why the Simulator didn't catch this

Comment: please, the code is not short. Which line throws that exception?

Comment: `object = [[self filteredListContent] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];` throws the error, in the `configureCell` method. Sorry. Should have made that more clear. Will update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array it is referencing is empty, it doesn't matter what index it is if you are trying to populate the tableview from an empty array.

Is your NSMutableArray `filteredListContent` populated (i.e. are you returning search results from the fetched results controller)?  Have you checked the contents of the array in `filterContentForSearchText:`?

P.S. I like your style... `BeerListTableViewCell` :)

Comment: Ha! Thought I pulled out all the beer references. Knew I was going to hear something about it if I didn't.

I'm populating the list inside `filterContentForSearchText`, but it never even gets there. The second I give focus to the search bar, I get the crash. Should I be loading it with a dummy value in `viewDidLoad` just to keep it from being empty?

Comment: That may be your problem is that you are configuring the cell before you even have data to configure the cell with.  You might need to delay configuration until after you have verified you have populated the array (or display a "No results" notification in the case of zero search results)

Comment: This is exactly the way Apple does it in their TableSearch sample code, though. And why would it affect the build on the Device, but not the Simulator? Configuring a cell when there isn't one seems like it would be a pretty consistant bug.

Comment: That's a good question, my only guess is that the simulator is a bit faster at fetching the search results so it populates the array in time.  It also looks like Apple is giving the `filteredListContent` array the same capacity as the data you are searching through via `self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.listContent count]];` whereas you are giving it the capacity of your search results count

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this **exact same crash** while working on an update to an existing app. The code is almost exactly the same as the original poster's and the only thing that changed in my app was the database.  There were **no code changes**.

With the old database, the table view datasource methods don't get called when the search display controller starts a search.

With the new database, the table view datasource methods *do* get called when the search display controller starts a search.

Same Core Data entities, same database structure, same code, same nibs. Same problem in simulator or on the device.